# Spark-excel conflicts with Java PoI ZipArchiveInputStream?

Tags: apache-poi

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: InputStream of class class org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipArchiveInputStream is not implementing InputStreamStatistics.
at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.util.ZipArchiveThresholdInputStream.(ZipArchiveThresholdInputStream.java:63)
at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.internal.ZipHelper.openZipStream(ZipHelper.java:180)
at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackage.(ZipPackage.java:104)
at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.open(OPCPackage.java:298)
at org.apache.poi.ooxml.util.PackageHelper.open(PackageHelper.java:37)
at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.(XSSFWorkbook.java:307)
at com.nielsen.utils.javapoi.AlterExcel.Excel_addColor(AlterExcel.scala:28)
at com.nielsen.process.statistics_xlsx.PerspectiveJob$$anonfun$dataETL$1.apply(PerspectiveJob.scala:113)
at com.nielsen.process.statistics_xlsx.PerspectiveJob$$anonfun$dataETL$1.apply(PerspectiveJob.scala:67)
at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.foreach(ArrayOps.scala:186)
at com.nielsen.process.statistics_xlsx.PerspectiveJob.dataETL(PerspectiveJob.scala:67)
at com.nielsen.trigger.Trigger$$anonfun$process$1.apply(Trigger.scala:22)
at com.nielsen.trigger.Trigger$$anonfun$process$1.apply(Trigger.scala:18)
at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
at com.nielsen.trigger.Trigger$class.process(Trigger.scala:18)
at com.nielsen.trigger.ComputingTrigger$.process(ComputingTrigger.scala:13)
at com.nielsen.trigger.ComputingTrigger$.main(ComputingTrigger.scala:79)
at com.nielsen.trigger.ComputingTrigger.main(ComputingTrigger.scala)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.JavaMainApplication.start(SparkApplication.scala:52)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:894)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:198)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:228)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:137)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
enter code here

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Upgrade your Apache Commons Compress to match the one that Apache POI requires?

Comment: Commons - COMPRESS InputStreamStatistics is not implemented. Maven does not package Commons - Compress jars.InputStreamStatistics cannot be implemented

Comment: To upload the commons-compresse-1.21.jar jar package to the cluster, run the following command
spark-shell --driver-class-path / home/xvinosh/m2 / repository/org/apache/Commons/Commons - compress / 1.21 / Commons - compress - 1.21 - jar